# Error installing jira on pip

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install jira on pip, but am getting the following errors:

```html
  /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins]#python -m pip install jira
Collecting jira
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))': /simple/jira/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))': /simple/jira/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))': /simple/jira/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))': /simple/jira/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))': /simple/jira/
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))': /simple/jira/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))': /simple/jira/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))': /simple/jira/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))': /simple/jira/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))': /simple/jira/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jira (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for jira
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: are you behing a firewall or proxy?

Comment: yes, is there are manual way to achieve that installation, or what needs to be provided as info to the network admin

Comment: as @karimtabet stated, are you in a container?

Comment: no, i`ve found the library, but don`t know how to install it manually - > https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jira/0.50

Comment: You have to download the tar.gz file (`jira-0.50.tar`), uncompress, go to the path and using a terminal type `python setup.py install`

Comment: Thanks, this is what i am doing at the moment, will let you know the outcome, as other libraries are required as well. I am testing on a VM with no proxy/firewall limitations

Comment: Issue is resolved, I have downloaded the libraries and added them manually. Thanks for the help.

Comment: using the way I told you?

Answer (score 0):

The `ProtocolError` says that pip is trying to resolve `/simple/jira/` as a DNS hostname instead of `pypi.python.org`. The problem may reside in `~/.pip/pip.conf`.

Are you in a container by any chance?