# pip upgrade fails inside virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to upgrade pip(version 7.1.0) to pip(version 9.0.1) inside a virtual environment using the command **pip install --upgrade pip**, the upgrade fails and shows the error (below) message

I followed this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333500/error-installing-jira-on-pip/36333625) and tried to locate pip.conf file inside my virtual environment, but there is no pip.conf file in my virtual environment and i also like to know what is a container in my virtual environment?. Thank you for your valuable inputs.

> You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 9.0.1 is available.
> You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip'
> command. Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None,
> redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection
> aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))': /simple/pip/
>
> Requirement already up-to-date: pip in
> ./lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py3.4.egg

Comment: It seems to be a network error. Maybe the problem was on pypi.python.org. Try again in case it works.

Comment: The "gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known" link is most certainly NOT an answer to this question.